# Altering the value of k in kNN algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, csv, machine-learning, knn

I have applied the KNN algorithm for classifying handwritten digits. the digits are in vector format initially 8*8, and stretched to form a vector 1*64..

As it stands my code applies the kNN algorithm but only using k = 1. I'm not entirely sure how to alter the value k after attempting a couple of things I kept getting thrown errors. If anyone could help push me in the right direction it would be really appreciated. The training dataset can be found [**here**](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet1.csv) and the validation set [**here**](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet2.csv).

**ImageMatrix.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ImageMatrix {
    private int[] data;
    private int classCode;
    private int curData;
public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
    assert data.length == 64; //maximum array length of 64
    this.data = data;
    this.classCode = classCode;
}

    public String toString() {
        return "Class Code: " + classCode + " Data :" + Arrays.toString(data) + "\n"; //outputs readable
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }
    public int getCurData() {
        return curData;
    }



}
```

**ImageMatrixDB.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ImageMatrixDB implements Iterable<ImageMatrix> {
    private List<ImageMatrix> list = new ArrayList<ImageMatrix>();

    public ImageMatrixDB load(String f) throws IOException {
        try (
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int lastComma = line.lastIndexOf(',');
                int classCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1 + lastComma));
                int[] data = Arrays.stream(line.substring(0, lastComma).split(","))
                                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                   .toArray();
                ImageMatrix matrix = new ImageMatrix(data, classCode); // Classcode->100% when 0 -> 0% when 1 - 9..
                list.add(matrix);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void printResults(){ //output results 
        for(ImageMatrix matrix: list){
            System.out.println(matrix);
        }
    }


    public Iterator<ImageMatrix> iterator() {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }

    /// kNN implementation ///
    public static int distance(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum += (a[i] - b[i]) * (a[i] - b[i]);
        }
        return (int)Math.sqrt(sum);
    }


    public static int classify(ImageMatrixDB trainingSet, int[] curData) {
        int label = 0, bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(ImageMatrix matrix: trainingSet) {
            int dist = distance(matrix.getData(), curData);
            if(dist < bestDistance) {
                bestDistance = dist;
                label = matrix.getClassCode();
            }
        }
        return label;
    }


    public int size() {

        return list.size(); //returns size of the list

        }


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        ImageMatrixDB trainingSet = new ImageMatrixDB();
        ImageMatrixDB validationSet = new ImageMatrixDB();
        trainingSet.load("cw2DataSet1.csv");
        validationSet.load("cw2DataSet2.csv"); 
        int numCorrect = 0;
        for(ImageMatrix matrix:validationSet) {
            if(classify(trainingSet, matrix.getData()) == matrix.getClassCode()) numCorrect++;
        } //285 correct
        System.out.println("Accuracy: " + (double)numCorrect / validationSet.size() * 100 + "%"); 
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Although your problem is with the `classify` method, I don't think it's a good idea to use euclidean distance for images. Once you stretch them you lose the correlation information. For example, two images belonging to the same person with different background colour will result high euclidean distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the for loop of **classify** you are trying to find the training example that is closest to a test point. You need to switch that with a code that finds **K** of the training points that is the closest to the test data. Then you should call getClassCode for each of those K points and find the majority(i.e. the most frequent) of the class codes among them. **classify** will then return the major class code you found.

You may break the ties (i.e. having 2+ most frequent class codes assigned to equal number of training data) in any way that suits your need.

I am really inexperienced in Java, but just by looking around the language reference, I came up with the implementation below.

```
public static int classify(ImageMatrixDB trainingSet, int[] curData, int k) {
    int label = 0, bestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int[][] distances = new int[trainingSet.size()][2];
    int i=0;

    // Place distances in an array to be sorted
    for(ImageMatrix matrix: trainingSet) {
        distances[i][0] = distance(matrix.getData(), curData);
        distances[i][1] = matrix.getClassCode();
        i++;
    }

    Arrays.sort(distances, (int[] lhs, int[] rhs) -> lhs[0]-rhs[0]);

    // Find frequencies of each class code
    i = 0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> majorityMap;
    majorityMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    while(i < k) {
        if( majorityMap.containsKey( distances[i][1] ) ) {
            int currentValue = majorityMap.get(distances[i][1]);
            majorityMap.put(distances[i][1], currentValue + 1);
        }
        else {
            majorityMap.put(distances[i][1], 1);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    // Find the class code with the highest frequency
    int maxVal = -1;
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: majorityMap.entrySet()) {
        int entryVal = entry.getValue();
        if(entryVal > maxVal) {
            maxVal = entryVal;
            label = entry.getKey();
        }
    }

    return label;
}
```

All you need to do is adding **K** as a parameter. Keep in mind, however, that the code above does not handle ties in a particular way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see what my problem was with my initial attempts after reading through yours, really helped.